# statistics on activity on a given tag over time?

Tags: support

Is there a link to statistics on how much activity there has been on a given tag over time? E.g. monthly numbers of questions (or views of questions) carrying the tag "logic-puzzle", say?

Comment: You could try [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks @Doorknob. I haven't seen that site before at all. Treasure trove for statistic nerds.... Maybe the more [direct link](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/queries) is useful too.